# How to change variable value inside compare() method of Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I want to get the count of repeating data while sorting it. For this, I'm using a Comparator. I want to increment the counter variable when the 2 objects being compared have same properties.

I have tried declaring a local variable and increment it inside the compare() method. But in order to use it inside compare method it needs to be declared as **final** but it its final then its value cannot be changed.

```
int counter = 0;
Collections.sort(drivDataList, new Comparator<DrivData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(DrivData o1, DrivData o2) {
        long l1 = o1.getTime();
        long l2 = o1.getTime();
        if (l1 > l2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (l1 < l2) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            counter++;
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
// use counter
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing this you have 2 options :

- Use an **integer array** instead of int

```java
final int[] counter = {0};
Collections.sort(drivDataList, new Comparator<DrivData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(DrivData o1, DrivData o2) {
        long l1 = o1.getTime();
        long l2 = o1.getTime();
        if (l1 > l2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (l1 < l2) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            counter[0]++;
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
//use counter
```

- Use a **custom class** with int property

```java
final MyCounter counter = new MyCounter();
Collections.sort(drivDataList, new Comparator<DrivData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(DrivData o1, DrivData o2) {
        long l1 = o1.getTime();
        long l2 = o1.getTime();
        if (l1 > l2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (l1 < l2) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            counter.incrementN();
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
// use counter

class MyCounter {
private int n;

public MyCounter() {
    this.n = 0;
}

public int getN() {
    return n;
}

public void incrementN() {
    this.n++;
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Update :**
As pointed out by @andrianekena-moise, you can also create a class with a counter field which extends Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `Comparator<DrivData>` in one class and declare counter as field inside this class like this :

```
 class Ddcomparator implements Comparator<DrivData> {

    int counter = 0;

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(DrivData o1, DrivData o2) {
        long l1 = o1.getTime();
        long l2 = o1.getTime();
        if (l1 > l2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (l1 < l2) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            counter++;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }
```

Then, You can get the `counter` variable after :

```
    Ddcomparator comparator = new Ddcomparator();
    Collections.sort(drivDataList, comparator);
    int counter = c.getCounter();
```